# How mount *.img file in centos 8 in fstab?

Tags: centos, mount

Create a virtual disk `samba.img` and mount it

```
fallocate -l 2G /root/img/samba.img
mkfs.ext4 /root/img/samba.img

sudo mkdir /srv/smb
sudo mount -t auto -o loop /root/img/samba.img /srv/smb
```

It works, but of course after a reboot you need to mount it again. According to `fstab` [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_file_systems/assembly_persistently-mounting-file-systems_managing-file-systems#con_the-etc-fstab-file_assembly_persistently-mounting-file-systems)

```
lsblk --fs /root/img/samba.img
```

And I get

```
lsblk: /root/img/samba.img: not a block device
```

I can’t find out the UUID and it’s not clear how to mount this disk file in `fstab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the path to the file in there:

```
/root/img/samba.img   /srv/smb   auto   defaults   0 0
```

You cannot refer the image using UUID because it isn't a block device (the filesystem on the image still has UUID but the system wouldn't be able to find the file by it because it's just a random file saved `/root`). I'm not sure if mounting an image using `fstab` is the best thing to do (I would probably use some startup script, systemd [mount unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) or an one shot systemd service), but a quick test shows it works the same way `mount` works.

Comment: Thank you, I understood my mistake `fstab` is not suitable, I will use another method